# How to insert elements in a map efficiently?

Tags: c++, dictionary

How to insert elements in a std::map efficiently? A common requirement is that if the map already has the element key, return false; otherwise insert it and return true. I cannot find a good ready method to do it.

```
template<class Key, class Value>
bool insert(Key const& key, Value const& value, std::map<Key, Value>& myMap);
```

Comment: You can use the variant of insert which returns a std::pair<iterator, bool>, which tells you whether it was an insert or not, or if you have access to C++11 you can use the insert-with-hint. See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) and click the "C++11" tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
template<class Key, class Value>
bool insert(Key const& key, Value const& value, std::map<Key, Value>& myMap)
{
    return myMap.emplace(key,value).second;
}
```

In case it's not available in your environment, you can use

```
template<class Key, class Value>
bool insert(Key const& key, Value const& value, std::map<Key, Value>& myMap)
{
    typedef typename std::map<Key, Value>::value_type value_type;
    return myMap.insert(value_type(key,value)).second;
}
```

Comment: @POW you need a map-value-type construct for that; i.e. a `std::pair<Key,Value>` (and I see Daniel already updated the answer to use the maps `value_type` typedef, which is how I would do it as well, but then-again, I use C++11, so.. I woudn't =) ).

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Daniels answer, may I suggest using insert() rather than emplace() and provide a separate emplace() method on your class if you need it?

The reason is that emplace() makes explicit constructors implicit. This means that if Value is non-copyable you will need to either use map.insert or ensure that Value provides a move assignment operator. The insert() also maintains backwards compatibility with pre C++11 compilers (if that is likely to be an issue).

```
template<class Key, class Value>
bool insert(Key const& key, Value const& value, std::map<Key, Value>& myMap)
{
    return myMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,value)).second;
}

template<class Key, class Value>
bool emplace(Key const& key, Value const& value, std::map<Key, Value>& myMap)
{
    return myMap.emplace(key,value).second;
}
```

Comment: If the value is non-copyable, how would your `emplace` work? Note that `emplace` for `map` is quite strange as it is the `value_type` that is constructed!